# SQL Server: How to call table valued function without providing input parameter values

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have a need to create a table valued function in SQL Server.  The function has input parameters, but all of them have default values.  If I want to SELECT from the function using default values for every input parameter, I cannot figure out how to call the function.

Below is the CREATE FUNCTION as well as my four attempts to call it without providing input-parameter values.  All four attempts failed:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx_my_table_valued_function
(@my_input_parameter AS VARCHAR(30) = 1)
RETURNS TABLE
RETURN SELECT 'x' AS my_column;

select * from fx_my_table_valued_function;
select * from fx_my_table_valued_function();
select * from [fx_my_table_valued_function];
select * from [fx_my_table_valued_function]();
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You have to use the DEFAULT keyword. Which is not very useful. http://rextester.com/ILQTK99749. There is no possibility to omit the parameter entirely as in other languages. Or as for stored procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx_my_table_valued_function
(@my_input_parameter AS VARCHAR(30) = 1)
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (my_column VARCHAR(max))
AS
BEGIN
RETURN 
END
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM fx_my_table_valued_function(default)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6f6c/1)